# PHP Laravel Getting Unique / Distinct String From Database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Basically I am creating a filter button to return query based on the string that was saved on the database. Here is my code:

```
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect">
            <option selected>Filter By Name</option>
            @foreach ($events as $event )
            <option value="{{ $event->event_parts }}">{{ $event->event_parts }}</option>

            @endforeach
        </select>

        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Filter</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Since they are strings, how do I create a distinct select option field retrieving only unique strings from the database?

I tried using distinct() and unique() but both returned with errors.

Comment: Can you provide the errors? Also, you could use `groupBy('field_name')`.

Comment: Please can you show your query code.

Comment: I was planning to use query route just to select the event details based on the string that is also stored in the db.

Answer (score 0):

change `$events` to `$events->unique('event_parts')`, which would filter out al non-unique `$events` based on the event_parts parameter (assuming it is a parameter, otherwise you'd use `->filter()` and with a callback function).

Comment: It lists out all the data of my db in an array but not the strings that I wanted to use as the select option.